# How to create a language select in my lightning component?

Tags: lightning, language

[image]

The language picker is like in above image.When the language is selected the custom labels used in page should be translated.

**Component:**

```
<aura:attribute name="ls" type="String"/>
<aura:attribute name="languageOptions" type="List" default="[
{'label': 'English (US)', 'value': 'en_US'},
{'label': 'Español', 'value': 'es'},
{'label': '中文 (CN)', 'value': 'zh_CN'},
]"/>
```

helper:

```
reloadPageForLanguage : function (cmp, event, helper) {

    var language = cmp.get("v.ls");
    alert("Language::"+language);
    var url = window.location.href.split('?')[0] + '?language=' + language;
    window.location.href = url;
},
```

still im unable to set the language.It will redirect to english after the page load.

**Controller:**

```
doInit : function (cmp, event, helper) {
        const values = [{
                'label' : $A.get("$Label.c.NN_Yes"),
                'value' : true
            }, {
                'label' : $A.get("$Label.c.NN_No"),
                'value' : false
            }
        ];
        var locale = $A.get("$Locale.language");
        alert("You are using " + locale);

        cmp.set("v.siteForFirstTime", JSON.parse($A.get("$Label.c.Survey_Yes_No")));
```

Comment: I've done that with changing the salesforce user language in apex. then refresh the page and all is good. Does that solution fit your needs?

Comment: @ItaiShmida is it possible to set the language directly in lightning and refresh the page?

Comment: It is possible to do this with apex, and invoke the apex method from lightning. If it is a viable solution for you, tell me and I will post it as an answer

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?